# how to set myweb directory instead of webapps in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

i am working in jsp webapplication in ubuntu. my tomcat6 is located =>/var/lib/tomcat6
here one folder is there "webapps".i have put my web page in webapps/ROOT. and i run from browser like localhost:8080/xyz.jsp it works fine. but now i want to change directory from webapps. for that i have create new directory testing123 in var/lib/tomcat. and configure in /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/server.xml which is given below.

```
        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="testing123"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

and restart tomcat and cut from webapps and pest  my xyz.jsp file in testing123 and try to run localhost:8080/xyz.jsp i get error 404. so kindlly tell me how to change directory.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[By default](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Deployment_With_Tomcat) Tomcat deploys webapps to the directory `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`. You can change the `$CATALINA_BASE`, if you want.

However, if you just want to deploy to your own application, not to `ROOT`, you also have to change the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/testing123/xyz.jsp
```

Comment: how to change $CATALINA_BASE/webapps

Comment: I don't know how to say this. I have been stuck on an error for 2 days. I did not expect that this answer from 2014 will fix my problem. Thank you Mr. Moritz Petersen. Wherever you are, I wish you good health and happiness.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder structure underneath webapps:

```
    /testing123/
       /WEB-INF/
            web.xml
```

In the web.xml put something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"     "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
  <display-name>testing123</display-name>
  <description>testing123</description>
</web-app>
```

Then put your jsp in testing123 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to clarify, why want you do such thing.

If you want to have testing instance than you should made the new CATALINA_BASE. 
It is set of folders and files separated from catalina_home that are used to create several running instances of single tomcat installation (catalina_home). 
For each you/can will set required configuration (listening ports,etc.).

There are several things you are trying to achieve (topic for your future research ).

1. Default/Root context application (runs at urls '/').
2. Exploded WAR (ROOT folder)
3. tomcat manual/automatic deployment

You should consider if there is no better way how to develop than modify files directly on server. That can lead to loss of source codes. 
So consider to use some SCM-tool (svn) and Maybe you should also take a look on maven to build a war artifact. (ROOT.war , will do the default context with automatic deployment for you )